# Test my AngularJS service against a real web api

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, protractor

I am tasked with writing an AngularJS app that connects to a RESTful API provided by our client. I want to wrap that API in an angular service and write tests against it using the real API. I am confused on how and where to do this.

Should I be using Protractor for this test? It doesn't involve any UX elements at all, so it doesn't feel like it should use Protractor.

Should I be using Karma? I tried Karma with $httpBackend, ngMockE2E and .passThrough() for all whenGET and whenPOST calls, but I'm having issues with `Unexpected request: POST` errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Karma. Protractor is for testing interaction with web pages.

Your `Unexpected request: POST` errors should be resolvable if you use `$httpBackend.expectPOST()` for each POST request you issue.

Comment: Thank you for the clearification. I think where I might be confused is, why do I need `$httpBackend.expectPOST()` when I am using `$httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();`

Comment: `whenPOST` sets up responses for certain requests. You set it up once, and it handles many requests. `expectPOST` is used for every request, meaning "a POST request should be sent here". It is to ensure that there are no stray HTTP requests, and that the intended requests were sent.